# How do I migrate Angular from 10 to 12 in a correct way?

Tags: javascript, angular, version

I am working on Angular project migration.
Initial project was of Angular 10 and now I am migrating it to Angular 12.
But the project is not running after migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `Throbber` which is of extension `.less` and you are trying to use that using `CSS-parser` that whats error is saying. Npm suggestion says : use [postcss-less](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-less) to parse it. I'm not sure it is being added by you or any third-party npm package.

I would suggest you to use `loading` icon that can be used using css or convert less code to css using online converter. you can check [here](https://www.webtoolkitonline.com/less-to-css.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is not only with that, I should have posted all errors but I was afraid that you might be confused or bored.

Comment: Let's take things step by step, I am sure there might be numbers of them. I have been through the same pain when we do the upgrade.

Comment: what do you think , I removed node-modules and node.js and reinstall npm package. Doesn't it harm to project? Or can be solution?

Comment: You should do that it will clean the state of npm packages and re-install them using `npm i` then run and see what happens.

Comment: I reinstalled packages: after running "npm install" , "ng v" gives error.D:\temp2\git_folder\angular-graph-pychart> ng v                                                 
ng : The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ng v
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ng:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Update the `angular-graph-pychart` and did you remove the node, angular and other dependencies? You just need to do that locally for you project.

Comment: I removed "node_modules" folder, node installation folder(in C: driver) and also npm-relavant folder(c:/usders/username/programdata/roaming/npm and its cache. And reinstalled node(LTS) and installed packages. And then installed angular/cli v12 . But launching also failed again. Until no solution.

Comment: The first problem was that "can't find @angular/localize/init" so I installed it running npm install @angular/localize and now the still problems are all css parser.

Comment: assets/app-assets/vendors/js/editors/tinymce/skins/lightgray/Variables.less - Error: assets/app-assets/vendors/js/editors/tinymce/skins/lightgray/Variables.less from Css Minimizer
D:\project\temp2\git_folder\angular-graph-pychart\assets\app-assets\vendors\js\editors\tinymce\skins\lightgray\Variables.less:1:4: Unknown word
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser [assets/app-assets/vendors/js/editors/tinymce/skins/lightgray/Variables.less:1,4]

Comment: You deed to parse less extension files or need to create a script which does the same. I haven't worked with less but added one package in the answer try that or may be any othe which you know or i guess try changing the angular config to use less?

Comment: Thanks, l am trying it now. And let you know the result.